# While using awk showing fatal : cannot open pipe ( Too many open files) error

Tags: awk

I was trying to do masking of file with command 'tr' and 'awk' but failing with error fatal: cannot open pipe ( Too many open pipes) error. FILE has approx 1000000 records quite a huge number. 
Below is the code I am trying :-

```
awk - F "|" - v OFS="|" '{ "echo \""$1"\" | tr \" 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\" \" QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM9876543210mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq\"" | get line $1}1' FILE.CSV > test.CSV
```

It is showing error :-

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1019) fatal: cannot open pipe `echo ""TTP_123"" | tr "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM9876543210mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq"' (Too many open pipes)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here
Also a Note any number of columns could be used for masking and can be at any positions in this example I have taken 1 and 2 column positions but it could be 3 and 10 or 5,7,25 columns 
Thanks
AJ

Comment: Not clear, please show us sample Input_file with expected output_file in code tags, so that we could try to help you.

Comment: You need to close the pipe each time. But is that all you're doing? Why not use `sed`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sorry can't show you 1000000 data records as this works for 1000 records

Comment: Kevin how should I implement this with SED or how should I use Close with my code could you show me please

Comment: That is why I mentioned sample(off course few lines only) which means how data looks like(even it may not have actual data, could have dummy values) but close to it so that we could know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: File sample
"201403310000"|"America"|"Washinton"|"Kevin"|"23457A"
201403310000"|"America"|"New York"|"Mark"|"23425A"
This would be the file with sample two records

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you can't have a space between `-` and `F` or `v`.

I was going to suggest `sed`, but as you only want to translate the first column, that's not as easy.

Unfortunately, `awk` doesn't have built-in `tr` functionality, so you'd have to use the shell like you are and just close the pipe:

```
awk -F "|" -v OFS="|" '{ 
    command="echo \"\\"$1"\\\" | tr \" 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\" \" QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM9876543210mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq\""
    command | getline $1
    close(command)
}1' FILE.CSV > test.CSV
```

However, I suggest using `perl`, which can do field splitting and character translation:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[0] =~ tr/0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM9876543210mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq/; print join("|", @F)' FILE.CSV > test.CSV
```

Or, for a shorter command line, just put the program into a file, drop the `e` in `-lane` and use the file name instead of the `'...'` command.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
I tried your close command solution but it only worked for 1 starting record for rest all the data did not get translated or we can say masked but Al least I didn't face the error but still all the I wanted to mask the data of 1st column at least with your solution could you please let me know that if this solution works for 1 record and not for other records, and please let me know what solution I can do for more than 1 records

Comment: This works for me, changing only the first field in every line ("201403310000"|"America" -> "EQWTQRRWQQQQ"|"America"). Do you want it to change the entire line?

Comment: No Kevin only the first column at least I will try again but in first time it only changed the 1st record rest all were the same as they were before

Comment: Kevin it's still the same only the first row it is changing the Unix script one not the rest

Comment: Well, it's working for me, so it's difficult to say what your issue could be. Did you try the perl version?

Comment: Actually I don't know much about PERL so that's why I am hesitating to try but still I will give it a shot but in the meantime Kevin if you can try your Unix solution with at least 5 records in file and see if it is still masking the data as mine it cannot

Comment: Kevin thanks maybe now it is working for me too I don't what or where I was doing wrong but it works many thanks :) and also there was a doubt if file has a header and I want to skip it in this UNIX procedure and do the masking thing for all other records what should I include in the code for skip = 1 header record

Comment: To skip the first row, add `NR > 1` in front of the block in awk: `awk -F "|" -v OFS="|" 'NR > 1 {...`

Comment: I guess this NR>1 would be used before every command I would be including in this code for multiple columns

Comment: I guess to mask I should have loaded the data into the tables and could use translate by masking a procedure or package for the same

Comment: Thanks Kevin much appreciated learned a lot today it wouldn't have been possible without you

Thanks and Regards
aKu

Comment: When using NR>1
Then it is only leaving 1 row but only of first column but it is still masking first row of 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

you can do the mapping in `awk` instead of making a system call for each line, or perhaps simply

```
paste -d'|' <(cut -d'|' -f1 file | tr '0-9' 'a-z') <(cut -d'|' -f2- file)
```

replace the `tr` arguments with yours.

Comment: Hi Karakfa,
When I ran the command with my file it hung up at one place and was waiting for some input I don't know why

Comment: not sure, works for me with the input you provided. Just test this as is with a sample file.  If sample test works then verify your data file.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but you can implement `tr` as an awk function that would save having to spawn lots of external processes

```
$ cat tr.awk

function tr(str, from, to,       s,i,c,idx) {
    s = ""
    for (i=1; i<=length($str); i++) {
        c = substr(str, i, 1)
        idx = index(from, c)
        s = s (idx == 0 ? c : substr(to, idx, 1))
    }
    return s
}
{
    print $1, tr($1,
        " 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        " QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM9876543210mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq")
}
```

Example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" hello wor-ld | awk -f tr.awk
hello KGCCN
wor-ld 3N8-CF
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn it is a useful piece of code would take it as a learning :)